# How can I use multiple crop in single image in angular 6

Tags: javascript, node.js, angular, mongodb

How can I use multiple crop in single image using ngx-image-cropper and get coordinates.

```
<image-cropper
    [imageChangedEvent]="imageChangedEvent"
    [maintainAspectRatio]="true"
    [aspectRatio]=" 4/3"
    [resizeToWidth]="128"
    [autoCrop] = true
    format="png"
    (imageCropped)="imageCropped($event)"

    (imageLoaded)="imageLoaded()"
    (loadImageFailed)="loadImageFailed()"
    (cropperReady) = 'cropperReady($event)'
    (startCropImage) = 'startCropImage($event)'
></image-cropper>`
```

Comment: this is the link https://www.npmjs.com/package/ngx-image-cropper   but it's using single cropping only

Comment: just update formatting, grammer

Comment: https://jsoma.github.io/kull/#/                                                                                  
here i give the link, i am expecting like this in angular 7